# Different value for same element in ByteArray?

Tags: c#, arrays, visual-studio, hex

Why am I getting byte 0x00 at index 0 instead of 0xD0 when calling the SetData() method from outside the class?

Here's a shortened down of the class:

```
using System;

namespace StackOverflow
{
    class Section
    {    
        uint _sectionId;
        byte[] _sectionData;

        public Section(byte[] sectionData) {
            _sectionData = sectionData;
            _sectionId = GetUShort(0x0FF4);
            Console.WriteLine(_sectionId + ": " + _sectionData[0].ToString("X")); // Gives D0
        }

        public void SetData() {
            switch (_sectionId) {
                case 0: SetTrainerInfo(); break;
                default: break;
            }
        }

        void SetTrainerInfo() {
            Console.WriteLine(_sectionId + ": " + _sectionData[0].ToString("X")); // Can Give 0

            byte[] deByte = GetBytes(0x00, 7);

            TrainerInfo.playerName = PkmString.GetString(deByte);
            Console.WriteLine(TrainerInfo.playerName + "name here");
        }
    }
}
```

Works fine if called in the Section constructor, but not from an external source like this:

```
using System;

namespace StackOverflow
{
    class SaveBlock
    {
        const short SECTIONS = 14, SECTION_SIZE = 4096;

        public Section[] sections = new Section[SECTIONS];

        public SaveBlock(byte[] blockData) {
            byte[] sectionData = new byte[SECTION_SIZE];
            for (int i = 0; i < SECTIONS; i++) {
                Array.Copy(blockData, SECTION_SIZE * i, sectionData, 0, SECTION_SIZE);
                sections[i] = new Section(sectionData);
            }
        }

        public void SetForAll() {
            foreach (Section sect in sections)
                sect.SetData();
        }
    }
}
```

And I get different bytes for the same element:
[image: Same byte is different]

Comment: Any reason not to post your code here instead of pastebin?

Comment: @L.B Code tends to become badly formatted on sites like these to my experience, especially Unity Answers.

Comment: And what you think now after my edit? OK?. just continue to post your shit. I can  edit it :)

Comment: @L.B Looks much better now, thank you. A x1000 times better than something like this for sure: http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/1250105/how-to-destroy-a-gameobject-in-update-thats-initia.html#answer-1250421 xD

Comment: OK, it is the problem of SO, not because of you haven't read the rules/helps of the site you post your question :)

Comment: Where are _sectionId and _sectionData defined? They are not in your class definition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at this code from the `SaveBlock` constructor:

```
byte[] sectionData = new byte[SECTION_SIZE];
for (int i = 0; i < SECTIONS; i++) {
    Array.Copy(blockData, SECTION_SIZE * i, sectionData, 0, SECTION_SIZE);
    sections[i] = new Section(sectionData);
}
```

The loop copies the `blockData` bytes to the `sectionData` array, and then uses `sectionData` to create a new `Section` object instance. Here's where things get tricky... **arrays are reference types**. That means the following line in your `Section` constructor is only copying the reference to the array:

```
_sectionData = sectionData;
```

As you move through the loop, you're copying data into the same array instance over and over, and then assigning that same array instance to the internal data of several `Section` objects. All of those objects are sharing the same array instance! It's very likely you want a **new array** for each of those objects:

```
byte[] sectionData;
for (int i = 0; i < SECTIONS; i++) {
    sectionData = new byte[SECTION_SIZE];
    Array.Copy(blockData, SECTION_SIZE * i, sectionData, 0, SECTION_SIZE);
    sections[i] = new Section(sectionData);
}
```

That may not be the only problem, as `_sectionId` is shown defined private an initialized to non-0. The `SetData()` method looks like this:

```
public void SetData() {
    switch (_sectionId) {
        case 0: SetTrainerInfo(); break;
        default: break;
    }
}
```

From the code we can see, there is no way that `_sectionId` will ever be `0`, and thus no way that `SetTrainerInfo()` is ever called.

Comment: Yeah, I probably stripped away just a little more than I should, as they were in the initializer field. But your answer solved the logic to my problem, thanks :D